# Alternate keys oData url is not working with Microsoft.AspNet.oData 7.1.0

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to add Alternate keys for my Edmmodel and later able to query it using oData url. I tried configuring the RouteBuilder in Startup file and added alternate ksys in Model Builder. But inspite of doing all the stuff I am still receiving 404 Not Found when I try to access the url https://localhost:44357/odata/books(ISBN='978-0-321-87758-1'). 
Below are the details

Here is my Startup.cs file

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
                IEdmModel model = GetEdmModel();
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odataRoute", "odata", containerBuilder =>
                {
                    containerBuilder.AddDefaultODataServices()
                        .AddService<IEdmModel>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
                            s => model)
                        .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
                            serviceProvider => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odataRoute", routeBuilder))
                        .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
                            s => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model));
                });

            });
        }

        private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");
            builder.EntitySet<Press>("Press");
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

            //Add alternate keys
            // first, find entity type
            IEdmEntityType booksEntityType = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Books").EntityType();

            // now find the properties we want to use as alternateKey
            var isbnEdmProp = booksEntityType.FindProperty("ISBN");
            // and finally add the annotation
            ((EdmModel)model).AddAlternateKeyAnnotation(booksEntityType, new Dictionary<string, IEdmProperty> {
                {
                    "ISBN", isbnEdmProp
                }
            });

            return model;
        }
```

BooksController.cs

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult GetByISBN(string keyISBN)
        {
            return Ok(_db.Books.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ISBN == keyISBN));
        }
```

**My Question**

```
1. When I try to access using alternate key with the url 
https://localhost:44357/odata/books(ISBN='978-0-321-87758-1') I am 
receiving 404 Not Found response. Can someone tell me what am I missing here ?
2. What I also noticed that with these changes even the basic routes like simple GET https://localhost:44357/odata/books is also not working
```

**Update**
I was able to isolate that below change is breaking all the existing routes. What is the correct way to configure Alternate keys ? Can someone help me what is wrong with the below configuration
.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
                            s => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model));

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to one of the following options:

- Adjust case in urls: https://localhost:44357/odata/**B**ooks(ISBN='978-0-321-87758-1')
- Manage the case-sensitivity explicitly while create AlternateKeysODataUriResolver instance:

```
.AddService<ODataUriResolver>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s =>
{
    var resolver = new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model);
    resolver.EnableCaseInsensitive = true;
    return resolver;
})
```